# How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, blob

I need to upload an image to NodeJS server to some directory. I am using `connect-busboy` node module for that.

I had the `dataURL` of the image that I converted to blob using the following code:

```
dataURLToBlob: function(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
        var parts = dataURL.split(',');
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
    }
    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
}
```

I need a way to convert the blob to a file to upload the image.

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: Files are Blobs, just tack on the meta properties and you're good to go.

Comment: The default for a blob when uploading it is `blob`. So, I first extracted the name of the file I was cropping and then gave the same `filename` so the cropped file while uploading it to server by doing `form.append("blob",blob, filename);`.

Comment: @skip did my answer below help out? Is so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

This function converts a `Blob` into a `File` and it works great for me.

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){
  //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
  theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  theBlob.name = fileName;
  return theBlob;
}
```

**TypeScript** (with proper typings)

```ts
public blobToFile = (theBlob: Blob, fileName:string): File => {
  const b: any = theBlob;
  //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
  b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  b.name = fileName;
    
  //Cast to a File() type
  return theBlob as File;
}
```

**Usage**

```js
const myBlob = new Blob();

//do stuff here to give the blob some data...

const myFile = blobToFile(myBlob, "my-image.png");
```

Comment: I think the cast should happen first so you don't need to use `any` in TypeScript. See [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20blobToFile(theBlob%3A%20Blob%2C%20fileName%3A%20string)%3A%20File%20%7B%0A%09%2F%2FA%20Blob%20is%20almost%20a%20File%20-%20it's%20just%20missing%20the%20two%20properties%20below%0A%20%20%20%20var%20f%20%3D%20%3CFile%3EtheBlob%3B%0A%20%20%20%20f.lastModifiedDate%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20f.name%20%3D%20fileName%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0A%7D) example.

Comment: This does not work for all purposes. Adding this "File" to an ajax call will not set the filename correctly.

Comment: This is not a good solution, the produced object still a blob.

Comment: @czupe It's been a while now, but if I recall correctly a file is a type of blob, so this should work

Comment: Hey Chris, I did not want to be offended you.
Just wanted point out the the object type will be Blob and not File :(.
Maybe I just needed something else.

Comment: Just add `b.__proto__ = File.prototype`, and your solution becomes a dream that even tricks `b instanceOf File` to `true`

Comment: Please note that `lastModifiedDate` is deprecated ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate ), you should now use `lastModified`, setting `lastModified` throws an error in Firefox if the blob accidentally happens to be an instance of File already.

Comment: this throws error Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '[object File]'

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205768/2557517 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663645/2557517 should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. new File() does not work straightforward on Cordova. Didn't realize that a file was just a type of blob if it weren't for this answer.

Comment: @JacobPoulRichardt You're correct, but this can can be fixed by adding the file name to the formdata like this:  formData.append("file", yourFileObj, yourFileObj.name);

Answer (score 425):

You can use the File constructor:

```
var file = new File([myBlob], "name");
```

As per the w3 specification this will append the bytes that the blob contains to the bytes for the new File object, and create the file with the specified name
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file

Comment: This is what I was looking for, the one difference is the first argument is actually an array so I used it as: var file = new File([myBlob], "name");

Comment: Yes. I am looking for this solution too. Stamplay server can not get the file name from blob object. So I need to convert it back to file. But Safari do not support file API... back to 0 now :(

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for this. Other solutions keep the file name to be 'bolb' whatever I changes it to, but your solution is keeping my file name.

Comment: File constructors do not work e.g. in PhantomJS: `TypeError: FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new File([''], 'file.pdf', {'size': 1000, 'type': 'application/pdf'})')`

Comment: Edge has currently (2017-10-04) a bug that prevents the usage of this constructor. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9551546/

Comment: Be sure to add file type, otherwise it will not work properly. new File([myBlob], "name", {
            type: "image/jpeg",
          });

Comment: this is throwing ` ReferenceError: File is not defined` for me

Comment: dumb way `fd = new FormData; fd.append('f', new Blob, "name"), fd.get('f')` :)

Comment: IE11 is not supporting new File() constructor, is there any alternative to convert a blob to File type ? assigning a filename and lastdateModified to blob is not working.

Comment: You can add image name using timestamp like this.
var file = new File([blobImage], `${Date.now()}.png`);

Comment: The File ctor method does not work for me on Ionic Capacitor on Native Devices - iOS, Android. Using the method that morphs the Blob object does work, however.

Answer (score 72):

*Joshua P Nixon*'s answer is correct but I had to set last modified date also. so here is the code.

```
var file = new File([blob], "file_name", {lastModified: 1534584790000});
```

**1534584790000** is an unix timestamp for "***GMT: Saturday, August 18, 2018 9:33:10 AM***"

Comment: Points for not breaking `instanceof` like the accepted answer

Comment: side note, if anyone is doing this and doesn't want to hard code that it was last modified in august 2018, you can always put `lastModified: Date.now()` and that'll return the current time in milliseconds! (just like how the example given is august 18 2018 at 9:33:10 in milliseconds)

Answer (score 41):

**Typescript**

```
public blobToFile = (theBlob: Blob, fileName:string): File => {       
    return new File(
        [theBlob as any], // cast as any
        fileName, 
        {
            lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
            type: theBlob.type 
        }
    )
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){       
    return new File([theBlob], fileName, { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: theBlob.type })
}
```

**Output**

[image: screenshot]

```
File {name: "fileName", lastModified: 1597081051454, lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 10 2020 19:37:31 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 601887, …}
lastModified: 1597081051454
lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 10 2020 19:37:31 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) {}
name: "fileName"
size: 601887
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

Answer (score 29):

For me to work I had to **explicitly provide the type** although it is contained in the blob by doing so:

```js
const file = new File([blob], 'untitled', { type: blob.type })
```

Answer (score 21):

My **modern** variant:

```
function blob2file(blobData) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.set('a', blobData, 'filename');
  return fd.get('a');
}
```

Comment: To add a filename to the resulting file use: `fd.set('a', blobData, 'filename')`

Comment: It fails in some IOS device when `fd.set`

Comment: I had to add the file name with the extension to make it work right. Like: `fd.set('a', blobData, 'filename.jpg')`

Answer (score 5):

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });

var file = new File([blob], "name.txt");
```

Now you can upload as .txt file

Answer (score 1):

This problem was bugging me for hours.
I was using Nextjs and trying to convert **canvas** to an **image file**.

I used the other guy's solution but the created file was **empty**.

So if this is your problem you should mention the **size** property in the file object.

```
new File([Blob], `my_image${new Date()}.jpeg`, {
  type: "image/jpeg",
  lastModified: new Date(),
  size: 2,
});
```

Just add the key the value it's not important.

Comment: size isn't a valid option

Comment: Not working bro !! , Blob is actually the object right ?

Answer (score -4):

I have used `FileSaver.js` to save the blob as file.

This is the repo : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

> Usage:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");

saveAs("https://httpbin.org/image", "image.jpg");
```

Comment: this dose not answer the question

Comment: he asked to convert a file not save a file