# Convert base64 to File Javascript outputs a weird structure (but not when converting it to Blob)

Tags: javascript, android, file

I need to convert media into File type to upload with JS.

The below code gives me the correct File output when taking a picture from the BUILT IN camera on my computer:

```
 const convertToFile = (base64: string) => {
let arr = base64.split(","),
  mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)![1],
  bstr = atob(arr[1]),
  n = bstr.length,
  u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

while (n--) {
  u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
}
const extension = mime.split("/")[1];
console.log(extension);
const fileName = new Date().getTime() + `.${extension}`;
return new File([u8arr], fileName, { type: mime });
```

};

Output =>
[image]

BUT when I try to convert a picture taken from my MOBILE PHONE CAMERA (runing it through the exact same code), this is the output that I get which is "corrupt".

[image]

**Please note I must convert this image to File, because of how the backend is structure I need to send it as a File (not as a Blob).

Comment: It looks like your mobile browser doesn't implement the File constructor properly(or at all). Use a Blob as a File is a Blob, whatever problems you are having using a Blob post it.

Comment: Wish I could help. Have you tried this approach?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553617/convert-blob-to-file

Comment: Thanks for your help. I indeed ended up just uploading the Blob and treating it in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to directly send a Blob and then treat it in the backend. For some reason the construction of a type File from my phone was not working properly