# The compatibility issue about new File([Blob],filename)

Tags: javascript

I use the constructor `new File([Blob],filename)`to convert Blob to File.
It works on **Chrome 56**.
but now the users require my system works on **Chrome blew 38**.
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript

Comment: What is purpose of converting `Blob` to `File`? `File` inherits from `Blob`

Comment: I need to upload the files to the **ali-oss** server by it's _API_. But it doesn't support **`Blob`** but **`File`** from now on.

Comment: I get a try to modify the **ali-oss**'s`API`.Just add a condition about the permission of `Blob`.What a surprise it works perfectly.