# Is there a way to convert a type of Blob image to a type of File in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, object, dom, types

I am using the ngx-image-cropper, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper, and need to programmatically set the default loaded image. The cropper provides an outlet to do so through the imageFileChanged API input. It requires a File type and any image I've attempted to pull in has been in Blob format.

Is there a way to convert a Blob to a File?

I haven't found any specific examples of someone doing this with this particular image cropper. I am open to using another one if this functionality is included and it's well supported.

I can successfully get a Blob image from our own server or a random api, I just haven't found a way to convert that to a File.

Is there an alternative to the HttpClientModule that would produce a different type?

The image cropper in its basic usage takes in an  file and uses that in the cropping tool. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

I'm happy to provide any code, I just don't know what would help in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Convert Only

```
let file = new File([blob], "name.extension");
```

If you are trying to download a blob and convert it to any file type, you do something like this. Since you said you are downloading and pulling an image.

> Fetch Convert, Download, Extension

```js
function download(url, filename) {
    // Request
    fetch(url, { 
        mode: 'no-cors' /*{mode:'cors'}*/
    // Callback
    }).then((transfer) => {
        // Return blob
        return transfer.blob();
    // Return data
    }).then((bytes) => {
        // Create an element
        let elm = document.createElement('a');
        // Add blob data to element
        elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(bytes);
        // Download blob data with certain extension
        elm.setAttribute('download', filename);
        elm.click()
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

download('http://BLOB', 'EXTENSION');
```

I think this is the convert function your looking for [How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript)

> Typescript:

```
public convert = (blb: Blob, f:string): File => {
    var b: any = blb;
    b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    b.name = f;
    return <File>theBlob;
}
    const Data = new Blob();
    let file = Convert(Data, 'extension');
```

Comment: Holy wow, thank you @Raymond. I googled all sorts of stuff and wasn't able to find the article you linked. This worked great for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @WilliamH. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is a duplicate. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript) will help you out. Thanks to @Raymond for pointing me to that article.