# Displaying a File() in the View from the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Is there a convenient way to display/Download a PDF file that is returned from the controller, the Controller retrieves a complex model and i am therefore using an Ajax call in order to call the ActionResult , the result received from the ActionResult is returned in the following format :

"%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
[/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
endobj
6 0 obj
....EOF"

Is there a way to assign this to a button to download , it is preferable that no Controller changes are required due to deployment issues with a client

i have tried to use a blob , however opening that blob returns a completely blank PDF

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Reporting/RenderRemoteReport",
  data: { reportSetup: reportSetup },
  success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    debugger;
    var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });
      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      $("#DLButton").attr("href",downloadUrl);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the blog data well then follow this might be helpful.

[How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript)