# converting a html element to a file

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have an html element of image

[image]

is it possible to convert that html element to become a file just like this

[image]

Any idea how can I do this? Do I need to use casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such.

You could:

1. [read the `src` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
2. make a fresh HTTP request to it [with `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
3. [convert the response to a blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)
4. [convert the blob to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript)

Comment: sir I have a question. I already converted the Blob to a file. However the converted file doesn't have a type eg. images/jpg. is there a way that i can include the type of the blob after it convert to file?

Comment: I use this var file = new File([myBlob], "name");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181292/19068

Comment: however it sets the type to a specific what if I use an image of png

Comment: nevermine i just got the type of blob via myblob.type and pass it as parameter. thanks btw