# How to convert Blob back into a file with nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, blob

I'm currently working on an application that allows the user to upload a file which gets sent to a express server that then converts that file into a bytearray that I can then store somewhere else.

However, I need to be able to convert this bytearray back into a file and send it back to the user. This is my current code in the express API:

```
app.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.files.file;
  const filePath = "divali";

  file.mv(filePath, async (err) => {
    const nfile = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    let fileData = nfile.toString("hex");
    let result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i += 2)
      result.push("0x" + fileData[i] + "" + fileData[i + 1]);

    console.log(result);

    var pfile = new Blob([result], { type: "application/pdf" });
    // var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(pfile);
    console.log(pfile);

    pfile.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    pfile.name = "some-name";

    console.log(pfile);
  });
});
```

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript/29390393

Comment: Not really.  I'm getting back a null when I use: theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  theBlob.name = fileName;
  return theBlob;

Comment: the File constructor method too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663645/3393804

Comment: I cannot use the File constructor. It says it's not defined. Is it in some nodejs module I can install?