# How to get File type object from url (image) in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I do have an image url lets say `http://localhost/sample.jpg`. i want to save this image url into a `File` object type as my component created. how can i achieve this with native js api?

```
export default {
  created () {
    const imageUrl = 'http://localhost/sample.jpg'
    const file = this.getFileFromUrl(imageUrl)
  },
  methods: {
    getFileFromUrl (url) {
      // ... what should i return?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simple ways to do this is using `fetch`.

```js
let url = '...'

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    ...
  })
```

After you have blob you can convert it to file. See [How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159179/2438933).

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/g725swht/)