# how to encode the voice record

Tags: react-native, flask, decode, encode

I just want to record voice clip in react native frontend. After that I want to pass it to the flask backend. If anybody can suggest some method or technology to do it? is it possible to use base64 encoding and decoding ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [ReactMic](https://github.com/hackingbeauty/react-mic) to record.
2. Transform the [blob into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript).
3. Then in Flask [get the file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/).