# Upload camera image to server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, server

I am coding a webpage where the user can take a photo with his phone camera, then the image will be processed and stored in the server.

I am storing the image content on a <canvas> an showing it with <img> tag but I don't know how to  send that information to the server.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by converting the canvas content into a **blob** and sending it to the server with fetch:

#### Canvas to blob

```js
someButton.onclick = (e) => {
   //some previous code
    canvas.toBlob(upload)
}
```

#### Upload Function

```js
function upload(blob) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("img_name",blob)
    fetch("/path/to/api", {
        method:'POST',
        body:form,
    }, ).then(res => res.text()).then(resp => console.log(resp))
}
```

Then the server treats the file as needed.

Comment: Are you sure that the server will handle the blob object? I would convert it to a File object before sending it to the server. See [How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663645/387194).

Comment: In my case it works perfectly fine. I'm using PHP and it gets included in the $_FILES array