# Can't use "fs" module inside of a Three.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, node.js-fs

I used [this](https://github.com/visionary-3d/morphing-visualizer-starter) base code to set up an app using Three.js. Now I want to use node's fs module to interact with my filesystem. I added the line `const fs = require("fs")` in my app.js, but it doesn't seem to find the module. The error output is

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js 93:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src'
resolve 'fs' in 'C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src
        single file module
          using description file: C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\package.json (relative path: ./src/fs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\fs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\fs.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\fs.jsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\fs.json doesn't exist
        C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\fs doesn't exist
      C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/fs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules\fs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules\fs.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules\fs.jsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules\fs.json doesn't exist
        C:\More\morphing-visualizer-starter-main\node_modules\fs doesn't exist
      C:\More\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-29 16:10-18

webpack 5.58.2 compiled with 1 error in 4320 ms
```

I'm very new to Javascript, so maybe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about the package/module system.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact you're using Three.js (a library for use in browers) and on the error stack you've posted, it looks like you're trying to use the Node.js `fs` module in **browser**-hosted code. You can't do that, it's only available within the Node.js environment.

It's a bit confusing, but originally both built-in Node.js modules and `npm` modules were **only** for use in Node.js, but then some bundlers started making it possible to use certain Node.js and `npm` modules in your browser-hosted code, by taking the code of the module and putting it in the JavaScript bundle for your page/app. But not all modules can be used in the browser; `fs` is one that can't be. If you need to access data from your server, you probably want [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Okay so the way I understand it now is that the code runs in the client's browser instead of on my server, so I can't use fs because it would access the client's filesystem. What I'm trying to achieve is take a screenshot of the threee.js canvas and save it on the server. How would I go about doing so? Fetch seems to be about downloading, but what I need is to upload

Comment: @Potheker - Despite the name, `fetch` can be used for *uploading* as well: You'd use an HTTP `POST` (typically) to send the data you want to save to the server. Some helpful posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924647/upload-camera-image-to-server-with-javascript/69925896#69925896