# converting blob to File object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, blob, backend

I am trying to convert Blob to a File object in nodejs. The Blob is passed from my frontend to my backend. I then want to convert it in my backend.

Here is my current code:

**frontend**

```
var data = {
  "file": file, //this is blob
  "file_name": bucket_string
};

return await axios.post(`/files/upload-file`, data);
```

**backend**

```
const file = new File(data['file'], "tests/" + customer + "/" + sound + ".wav");
```

Currently this throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
```

How can I properly convert the data in nodejs?

Comment: See the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663645

Comment: I attempted that above @ErikMichelson and got this: ReferenceError: File is not defined

Comment: Nevermind, you're using node.js and not a browser. Node.js doesn't have the File class implemented. However, for working with files you have the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module integrated in node.

Comment: @ErikMichelson so how can i use fs to convert blob to .wav File object

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the File object? If you're just interested in storing the wav file to disk, take a look at [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so sorry that this is a full post. File is an interface in TypeScript but does not specifically exist with node.js (sans TypeScript). I don't see anything referencing TypeScript in your code so maybe it's because you're not using typescript. For information on the `File` interface reference the docs [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.file.html). Without knowing if you're using typescript I'm not sure what more to say about the File interface.

Comment: I guess @Juliette isn't looking for the TypeScript File class, but for the [web implementation of File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File). However, that exists only for browsers.